# Raw loader with ES6 imports

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, raw-loader

I'm trying to use ES6 with webpack. Its okay for javascript module imports/exports, but I can't get raw-loader to work.

Here is what I am intending to do in my source file

```
import template from './template.html'
```

The template.html file has raw HTML in it.

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/app.js',
  ],
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: __dirname + '/app/',
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
      },
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: __dirname + '/app/',
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        include: __dirname + '/app/',
        loader: 'raw-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: './build/',
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
};
```

When I launch webpack, the code is generated as so:

```
  module.exports = "module.exports = \"  hello\\n  <div>\\n    <ul>\\n      <li ng-repeat...
```

It should only be the `"hello\n <div>..."` string that should be exported.

Any help on this ? I really don't understand how to do this.

Comment: "It should only be" --- should it? https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader/blob/master/index.js#L8

Comment: Nop. With default webpack imports it is module.exports = "Hello ...". This is a problem from my es6 configuration.

Comment: Have you tried using the [`html-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader) instead of the `raw-loader`?

Comment: 4 years later, "webpack 5 can generate both ES5 and ES6/ES2015 code now"..

Answer (score 4):

Import with raw-loader returns object with default property (import * as template from './file'). You can call it template.default to get what you want.

Here was the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458511/how-to-use-es6-import-for-images/42458001#42458001)

And here you cant give a glance the way how you can [update code of raw loader](https://github.com/brumkorn/es6-raw-template-loader.git) to use imported value as it is. Just have tinkered with this for a while