# How to use es6 import for images

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I'm using es6 and want to import an image to use with webpack. Looking at the [file-loader doc](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader), this is the example they gave:

```
var url = require("file!./file.png");
```

url will now return something like `/static/351f9446b3ba577b6a79e373e074d200.png`

This works with require, but how do I use `import` to do this, I've tried -

```
import * as url from '../images/151.png';
```

but that doesn't work because url remains undefined. How do I set a variable to what I'm importing when it's an image?

Comment: Maybe this library will help 
https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader

Comment: i've tried using that but it doesn't work

Comment: "That doesn't work"—how does it not work? Please explain.

Comment: please see edit - the require will return something but not the import

Comment: import url from 'file!./file.png'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> import * as url from '../images/151.png';
>
> but that doesn't work because url remains undefined. How do I set a variable to what I'm importing when it's an image?

Using Webpack 2.0 with file-loader plugged-in. It works in my case, but import returns something like object bytemap instead of data-uri string;

And this object has the 'default' property, that contains the same data, as if it was required.

Honestly I'm not sure what is that object, and why there is the default property but that's how I've made it work.

```js
import '../css/bootstrap.css';
import '../css/app.scss';
import * as url from '../images/webpack_logo.png';

let img = document.createElement('img');
img.style = {
  height: '25%',
  width: '25'
};
debugger;


img.src = url.default;
console.log('imported', url);

document.getElementById('img_container').appendChild(img);
```

The way mentioned in previous answer returned undefined, btw. And it's expected, because that syntax relies on default export to be declared on the source module.

Answer (score 12):

Using [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) you can achieve this with the nice and simple syntax of:

```
import youNameIt from "../images/151.png";
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do you use `youNameIt` within your actual file to display your image on to page?

Comment: Well, what you imported is a path to the image so you can use it for example like this: <img src=youNameIt/>

Answer (score 11):

Use

`import url from "file!./file.png"`

Comment: Are you sure about this ? I got this error : ```Unable to resolve "file!./backgrounds/plan.jpg" from "example/index.js" 
Failed building JavaScript bundle.```

Answer (score 4):

With webpack 4 & es6 I used:

```
const url = require('../images/webpack_logo.png');
```

then used this as the `src="url"` in my `<img>` tag.