# How to upload files (image files) in a stackblitz editor?

Tags: reactjs, image

This is my project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cu1smg?file=src/images/react_logo_icon.pngfile=src%2Fimages%2Freact_logo_icon.png

I'm currently learning React JS and I need help on uploading an image file to this editor. I want it uploaded in the "react_logo_icon.png" file in the "images" file. I looked everywhere for an image upload option/button, but I couldn't find it.

I searched the exact same functionality in a similar editor called codesandbox, and it was there, but I couldn't find it on stackblitz(current editor i'm working on)

So if you could please help me, that would be great!
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458511/how-to-use-es6-import-for-images maybe this will help

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to import the image, i just want it in that react_logo_icon file. Do you know how to upload an image to the stackblitz editor?

Comment: you want to change the image file `react_logo_icon.png` to have a different image?

Comment: No, currently react_logo_icon doesn't have an image. It's just an empty file. I want to upload an image to the editor and put that image in that file(react_logo_icon.png)

Comment: just upload an image and change the name of it to `react_logo_icon.png`

Comment: that's the problem. I don't know how to upload an image in stackblitz. I just created an empty file and named it `react_logo_icon.png`

Comment: it wasn't clear at all from your question... please rewrite it and change the title... it doesn't have anything to do with react, it's a question about a code editor.

Comment: I changed the title, but I think the description is pretty clear. `I'm currently learning React JS and I need help on uploading an image file to this editor. I want it uploaded in the "react_logo_icon.png" file in the "images" file.`

Comment: When I try to upload it says that I need a pro account... so I guess unless you have a pro account you cant upload images

Comment: Can you please show me a screenshot of which button or where you clicked to upload?

Comment: I dragged an image from my desktop to the editor...

Comment: Yeah, i tried that, but it had no effect in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

You can attempt to upload an image file to the StackBlitz editor by dragging and dropping. However, without a paid membership, you will get this error message:

[image: StackBlitz image upload error message.]

If you're project is on GitHub, you can clone your repository (images included) into a StackBlitz project by prepending your project's GitHub URL with the StackBlitz domain:

*stackblitz.com/github/`<username>`/`<repo-name>`*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually that might have changed. Just dropped an image successfully without a paid membership !

Answer (score 0):

you can create an assets folder.
then upload photos to the assets folder.
you can then reference the images in your project.

Note upload photos is a premium feature.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A of December 2023, I needed to **sign in** (without a paid membership was enough).

Otherwise it would fail silently to upload files larger than a couple kilobytes. (You could actually see the request in the network dev tools returning the error "sign in required" but the GUI didn't show the error.)

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here][1]

Giahaa
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Pnf.jpg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What's not clear? I guess, for a bot it's not, but for humans it is: by providing a link to imgur image, this person states that you don't actually need to pay to Stackblitz to use images - you can use any free image hosting service.